# Team Member can't download Distribution Provisioning

Tags: ios

I am a `Team Member` in our company's iOS Program. I finished developing an app for the company and I am about to submit it to the app store. The problem is I can't download a Distribution Profile for the app. Whenever I go to the Provisioning tab in the iOS Provisioning Portal, all I see are the Development Provision of every app the company has made. There is no Distribution tab, so I don't really know where can I download the distribution provision.

I read somewhere that a Team Member can only download provisioning profiles. So where can I download the distribution provision if the Distribution tab is not even visible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get credentials as a *Team Agent*. The distribution tab will then appear and be available to create new provisioning profiles.

Alternatively, your *Team Agent* can give you *Admin* privileges in the Member Center / People section of Apple's developer site.

<strike>Alternatively, your *Team Agent* or a *Team Admin* can download the provisioning profile and email it to you.</strike> [**not tested**]

Also, an *Admin* can invite another person to be *Admin*. On the Apple developer website, go to *Member Center - People - Invitations*, click on *Invite Person*, and there you can specify the role which includes *Admin*.

[Here is an overview](https://developer.apple.com/membercenter/help.action?programType=iphone) of all the developer program roles.

Comment: The third given alternative does not work that way. You will also need the private key, and the distribution certificate.

Comment: It think it works if it is for the app store... Could be wrong.

Comment: An admin is enough. I described the procedure in my answer.